# Setting Liquibase changeset id in case of includeAll

Tags: liquibase

I have a changelog file sth like this :

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9 http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
    <includeAll path="tables" relativeToChangelogFile="true" /> 
    <includeAll path="latest/triggers" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    <includeAll path="latest/functions" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    <includeAll path="latest/procedures" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    <includeAll path="latest/views" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />       
    <changeSet author="myname" id="CHANGESET_ID" />
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Copied [from](http://www.liquibase.org/tutorial-using-oracle)

I am just confused to set the CHANGESET_ID  in `<changeSet author="myname" id="CHANGESET_ID" />`

Should it be the least changeset number or greatest changeset value  ?

Do we need it all to-gather here in this file ?

I ll appreciate someone explain how to set changeset value properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `<changeSet>` there (but you could include any). Regarding naming the changesets the [LiquiBase  Best Practices Page](http://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices) states:

> Choose what works for you. Some use a sequence number starting from 1
>   and unique within the changelog, some choose a descriptive name (e.g.
>   'new-address-table').